# Calculate Time Difference Between difference rows without lead/lag

Tags: sql, sql-server, clickhouse

I have a live-dashboard with a new row being added to the table every time a new status is recorded.

| Status | Start_Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-23 09:23:43 |
| 0 | 2023-08-23 08:23:34 |
| 1 | 2023-08-23 05:20:05 |
| 3 | 2023-08-23 02:16:21 |

I want to write a SQL query to create a output that would give me the Stop_time of each Status and for the first row, it would use now().

OUTPUT:

| Status | Start_Time | Stop_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-23 09:23:43 | now() |
| 0 | 2023-08-23 08:23:34 | 2023-08-23 09:23:43 |
| 1 | 2023-08-23 05:20:05 | 2023-08-23 08:23:34 |
| 3 | 2023-08-23 02:16:21 | 2023-08-23 05:20:05 |

Please note, I cannot use LEAD/ LAG functions as the SQL is an older version.
I know this can be done simply with LAG but that function is not available for me.

I tried using the MIN and ORDER BY although it did not create the correct row shift and neither could I add the now() value for the first row

Thank you!

Comment: `as the SQL is an older version` how old? All supported versions, and many *unsupported* ones, have LAG

Comment: Just use a sub-query

Comment: And clickhouse appears to be a totally different rdbms? Why have you tagged it? And how is Grafana relevant?

Comment: Data is saved in Clickhouse. My dashboard is in Grafana (community edition). That's where my SQL Query is written.

Comment: If you can't `LAG`/`LEAD` then you are using at *"best"* SQL Server 2008. SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support *over* **4 years** ago; it is long past time you implemented your finalised upgrade path at this point. Using such an old, insecure, version is quite irresponsible at this point. If you aren't even using 2008 then the version is even older and the problem even more compounded.

Comment: If the query you need is going to run against SQL server then please don't tag clickhouse and grafana as they just confuse things. Or maybe it's SQL server you need to remove?

Comment: And please show us your attenpt

Comment: you can use a correlated subquery to get previous row like: select *, (select top 1 date from yourtable t2 where t2.date < t.date order by t2.date desc) from yourtable t

Comment: @Tani1297 are you using `Microsoft SQL Server`?

Answer (score 0):

If the database is so old you may need to use a correlated subquery. The following is an example only it may not work as is:

```
Select
  Status
, start_time
, coalesce(
   (Select max(t2.start_time)
    from your_table as t2
    Where t.start_time < t2.start_time)
    ,NOW()
    ) AS stop_time
From your_table as t
```

Nb you may need ISNULL instead of COALESCE

Answer (score 0):

if row_number() is available in your SQL-server version try something like this

```
begin try 
create table #test ([status] int, start_time datetime)

insert into #test ([status], start_time)
values (1, '2023-08-23 09:23:43')
    ,(0, '2023-08-23 08:23:34')
    ,(1, '2023-08-23 05:20:05')
    ,(3, '2023-08-23 02:16:21')
end try
begin catch
end catch

;with cte as (
    select *
        ,rn = row_number() over (order by start_time desc)
        from #test
        )

select 
    a.[status]
    ,a.start_time
    ,stop_time = isnull(b.start_time,getdate())
from cte a
left join cte b
on a.rn = 1 +b.rn
```

obviously you don't need the try/catch part because you already have a table with status and start_time columns.

Comment: I tried left join and had an error message- Join causes exception memory limit for query. I have seen this before using JOIN on clickhouse data

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
    Status INT,
    Start_Time DATETIME
);
```

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (Status, Start_Time) VALUES
    (1, '2023-08-23 09:23:43'),
    (0, '2023-08-23 08:23:34'),
    (1, '2023-08-23 05:20:05'),
    (3, '2023-08-23 02:16:21');
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
SELECT 
    t1.Status, 
    t1.Start_Time,
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.rn = 1 THEN GETDATE()
        ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 Start_Time FROM (
            SELECT Start_Time, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Start_Time DESC) as rn
            FROM your_table_name
        ) t2 WHERE t2.rn = t1.rn - 1)
    END AS Stop_Time
FROM (
    SELECT Status, Start_Time, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Start_Time DESC) AS rn
    FROM your_table_name
) t1
ORDER BY t1.Start_Time DESC;
```

| Status | Start_Time | Stop_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-23 09:23:43.000 | 2023-08-23 10:47:29.030 |
| 0 | 2023-08-23 08:23:34.000 | 2023-08-23 09:23:43.000 |
| 1 | 2023-08-23 05:20:05.000 | 2023-08-23 08:23:34.000 |
| 3 | 2023-08-23 02:16:21.000 | 2023-08-23 05:20:05.000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cRDJ6YKH)